# What is the simplest, easiest algorithm for finding EMST of a complete graph of order 10^5

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, np-complete, polynomial-approximations

I just want to be clear that EMST stands for Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree.

Essentially, I have been given a *file with 100k 4D vertices (one vertex on each line). The goal is to visit every vertex in the file* while *minimizing the total distance traveled*. The distance from a point to another point is simply the Euclidean Distance (Distance if you draw a Straight Line between two points".

I already know that this is pretty much the *Traveling Salesman Problem*, which is NP Complete, so I am looking to approximate the solution.

The first approximation algorithm that came to my mind is by finding the MST from a graph constructed from the file... But that would take O(N^2) to even just construct all the edges from the file given the fact that it's a complete graph ( I can go from any point to another ). And given that my input is N = 10^5, my algorithm will have a huge running time, which is too slow...

Any ideas on how I can plan on approximating the solution? Thank you very much..

Comment: Do you need to return to the same vertex you start at? Can you visit a vertex more than once, or an edge more than once? I ask because a MST does not have these restrictions, while the TSP does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you actually want a EMST as your title suggests, and the TSP is just a means to that end, and not the actual goal itself. The two have very different restrictions (the TSP being far more restrictive), and thus very different optimal solutions.

### Overview

The idea is that we want to run a modified kruskal's algorithm, which will make use of a k-d tree to find the closest pairs without evaluating every potential edge. We can find the shortest edge to each vertex in a connected component, take the shortest overall, and connect our connected components via that edge. As you'll see, this connects at least half of our connected components each iteration, so it takes at most `logn` iterations to complete.

### Nearest Neighbor Search

For constructing an EMST, you'll want to use a data structure for querying for nearest neighbors in 4D space. You could extend octrees to work in a higher dimension, but I'd personally go with a k-d tree. You can construct a k-d tree in `O(nlogn)` time using the median of medians algorithm to find the median at each level, and you can insert / remove from a balanced k-d tree in `O(logn)` time.

Once you've built a k-d tree, you'll want to query for the nearest neighbor to each point. We'll then construct the edge between these two vertices. Many of these edges will be duplicated, as for some vertices `A` and `B`, `A`'s nearest neighbor may be `B`, and `B`'s nearest neighbor may be `A`. We'll handle this by storing which connected component each vertex belongs to, and after two vertices are joined by an edge, the duplicate edge will clearly connect two vertices of the same connected component, and so we'll discard it. To accomplish this, we'll use a disjoint-set (just like in many implementations of kruskal's algorithm) to assign a connected component to each vertex. This will also prevent us from creating cycles in our graph, which would introduce unnecessary edges in the MST.

### Merging

However, as we construct each edge, we'll want to insert it into a min-heap priority queue before checking which edges to keep and which edges connect already-connected vertices. This will not affect the outcome of this first iteration, but later on we will need to handle edges by increasing distance. Then dequeue all the edges, check for unnecessary / redundant edges via the disjoint-set, insert valid edges into the MST, and merge the respective disjoint-sets. All of this of course introduces a `nlogn` factor for constructing and dequeuing elements from the min-heap (we could also just sort them in a plain array, if we wished).

After this first iteration of adding edges, we'll have connected at least half of the MST, maybe more. This is because for each vertex we added one edge, and we can have at most one duplicate per edge, so we've added a few as `vertices / 2` edges, but as many as `vertices - 1`. Now at least 1/2 of our MST has been built. We'll continue the process as described in the following paragraphs, until we've added `vertices - 1` edges in total.

### Generalizing NN-Search

To continue, we'll want to construct lists of the vertices in each connected component, so that we can iterate over them by groups. This can be done in nearly linear time, as searching (also merging) a disjoint-set takes `O(α(n))` time (`α` being the inverse ackermann function) and we repeat exactly `n` times. Once we have our lists of vertices per connected component, the rest is fairly straightforward. We'll take our existing k-d tree, and remove all the vertices in our current connected component. We'll then query for the nearest neighbor to each vertex to each vertex in our connected component, and add these edges to our min-heap. We'll then add these vertices back into the k-d tree, and repeat on the next connected component. Since we insert/remove a total of `n` elements, this amounts to an average case `O(nlogn)` time complexity.

Now that we have a queue of the shortest potential edges connecting our connected components, we'll dequeue these in order, and just as before insert valid edges and merge the disjoint sets. For the same reasons as before, this is guaranteed to connect at least half of our components, maybe even all of them. We'll repeat this process until we have connected all vertices into a single connected component, which will be our MST. Note that because we halve the number of disconnected components each iteration, it'll take at most `O(logn)` iterations to connect every vertex in our MST (most likely far less).

### Remarks

Overall, this will take `O(nlog^2(n))` time. There will likely be far less than `log(n)` iterations however, so expect a speedup there in practice. Also note that R-tree might be a good alternative to the k-d tree- I don't know how they compare in practice however.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's quadratic-time, but I think you should consider Prim with an implicit graph. The structure of the algorithm is

```
for each vertex v
    mindist[v] := infinity
    visited[v] := false
choose a root vertex r
mindist[r] := 0
repeat |V| times
    let w be the minimizer of d[w] such that not visited[w]
    visited[w] := true
    for each vertex v
        if not visited[v] and distance(w, v) < mindist[v]:
            mindist[v] := distance(w, v)
            parent[v] := w
```

Since the storage used is linear, it will likely stay resident in cache, and there are no fancy data structures, so this algorithm should run pretty fast.

Comment: I would definitely be interested in seeing how this plays out if OP ends up implementing this. Its far simpler, but as you said still quadratic.

Comment: I think I really over-explained my alternative. Its really just kruskal's but without adding all the edges to the priority queue immediately- instead just getting the nearest edge to all vertices via a k-d tree, repeatedly as needed.

Comment: (10^5)² is 10^10, so will take a few seconds if properly implemented. To be compared to, say, 10.16.10^5 (milliseconds) assuming an asymptotic constant 10 times larger with an O(n log n) algorithm.